# How to a canvas in a div for a specific piece of data? (beautifulsoup)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

mcname = input("IGN: ")
url = "https://namemc.com/" + str(mcname)

r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, "lxml")

skinhash = soup.find("canvas",{"class":"skin-3d drop-shadow auto-size align-top"})
print(skinhash)
```

The url varies from the name of the player
skinhash is finding the subsection I want that has the data I want in it

When I run it, it returns

```
<canvas class="skin-3d drop-shadow auto-size align-top" width="270" height="360" style="cursor:move;width:270px" data-skin-hash="eaca61b4767f0644" data-model="slim" data-flip="false" data-animate="false" data-cape-hash="db9048770988a943" data-theta="30" data-phi="21" data-time="90"></canvas>
```

All I want is the string value for the data-skin-hash

Does anyone know how to grab a specific piece of data from here and print it as a string?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access to it's attribute `data-skin-hash`.
Try this:

```
print(skinhash['data-skin-hash'])
```